# Which visa for business travel to USA from Australia?

Tags: usa, visas, esta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UK citizen, US company, living in UK: Can I use an ESTA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9245/uk-citizen-us-company-living-in-uk-can-i-use-an-esta)

I will be traveling to the US from Australia to observe and help with the installation of equipment that my company will be bringing back to Australia.  Do I need a business visa, and work visa or can I get APEC.  I have ESTA as I travel to the US to visit family.

Comment: I'm going to close this question off a duplicate of a previous one and merge it, as it covers exactly the same ground on what distinctions are made between work visas.