# UK citizen, living in India and working in India: Can I use an ESTA to work for 2 months in the US?

Tags: usa, visas, work, uk-citizens, esta

So,

- I am an UK Citizen.
- Currently living & working in India.
- Can I use ESTA to work for 2 months in US for my employer's client in the US?
- I will not be getting any salary or money for these 2 months from my Indian employer for working in US. I will get only my expenses for these 2 months.

Comment: For all due purpose, this is a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9245/uk-citizen-us-company-living-in-uk-can-i-use-an-esta  The exact situation is slightly different, but those differences are not relevant, and thus the answer is exactly the same.

Comment: However, questions should be closed if the questions are the same, not if it happens that the same answers apply.

Answer (score 5):

You should not have any issues with arriving here under ESTA for business purpose.

If you want more details you can take a look at the [FAQ](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm) posted on the [DHS Visa Waiver Program](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) site as long as you arrive on [VWP Signatory Carrier](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/list/kw/visa%20waiver%20program%20signatory%20carriers) ([which as you can you can see for yourself](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/87163.pdf)) is a pretty extensive list.

Answer (score -3):

As with all such questions: ask at a consulate or embassy!
That aside, ESTA is a tourist visa program, not a work permit. Therefore I'd expect it to not be valid for business travel (which yours would be). While they may not mind someone using it to attend a tradeshow for a few days, or a conference, as an agent for a foreign company, your plans are quite different. You're going to be putting a US resident out of a job (or preventing one from getting a job), which is the very reason foreigners need work permits as companies have to show they can't get local people qualified before a foreigner is allowed in to perform the work (or that's the theory at least behind such things).
But as said, ask at an embassy or consulate.

Comment: The Visa Waiver Program IS valid for business travel - it's definitely not a "tourist visa program"

Comment: but it's NOT a work permit, and for what he's doing he's going to require one!

Comment: @jwenting [According to DHS the Visa Waver Program](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#vwp3) is valid for Business Travel as long as it is less then 90 days.  And I am not sure what does any of this have to do with American resident being out of a job?