# Is leaving the US for a couple of days enough to get another 3 months in the country?

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program, visa-runs

I hope someone can help me.

I am currently on holiday for 3 months in America under the Visa Waiver Program and would like to stay an extra 2 or 3 weeks. I know I will have to leave the country, renew my visa waiver and then reenter and so wanted to know if I will have an issue reentering.

I will only be out of the country for about 24 to 48 hours, just enough to renew the visa and get on a plane. I understand it is up to the border control person on the day, but does anyone think I will have an issue??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it a good idea to mention to the USA immigration officer that I'm visiting my girlfriend?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61825/is-it-a-good-idea-to-mention-to-the-usa-immigration-officer-that-im-visiting-my)

Comment: @chx there are certainly similarities with the proposed duplicate question, but the central issue of the other question is the premise for the visit, which is not even disclosed here.

Comment: Ellen: while the linked duplicate implies that you need to spend 91 days out of the country after spending 90 days in it, do note that this is a "rule of thumb." You stand a (probably small) chance of being allowed in for a second stay if you have a very good reason for your additional visit and strong evidence supporting a conclusion that you won't stay any longer than two or three weeks. On the other hand, it's probably more likely that you'd be denied entry. A safer course of action in your case would be to leave the US and apply for a B-2 visa, which allows longer visits than does the VWP.

Comment: You already know I presume that you have to leave the continent - that going to Canada, Mexico or the Caribbean won't reset the VWP?

Comment: My wife did this twice before we were married and got her proper visa. We spent a few days in Costa Rica before returning to the USA. Both times she was readmitted without any trouble for another 90 days. Why Costa Rica? Because it was the closest country which is just far enough to trigger the VWP reset YMMV ...

Comment: It depends very much on your personal circumstances, and you should expect the CBP officer to look deeply into those. Going to secondary is almost guaranteed. Getting in is not.

Comment: @brhans great comment, +1. Could you specify when this was (which year)? And maybe make it an answer?

Answer (score 3):

> Is leaving the US for a couple of days enough to get another 3 months in the country?

Just leaving (US and [adjacent islands](http://lexpeakimmig.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/what-is-contiguous-territory-and.html) etc) is sufficient to 'start again' as the US sets no fixed minimum absence between visits under the VWP.
From [CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1072/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDc1NjA1MjA5L3NpZC9wbG9UUGcqbQ%3D%3D/~/esta---length-of-approval):

> There is no set requirement for how long you must wait between visits.

However the same site also cautions:

> there should be a reasonable amount of time between visits so that the CBP Officer does not think you are trying to live here

So the answer to your question is quite likely "**No**" since 180 day residence out of 181 or 182 days looks like trying to live in USA.  Apparently CBP have indicated that, as a [rule of thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb) after a 90 day visit they would be looking very closely at reasons for any return within 91 days.

However, you mention that your intention is only to extend your visit by 2 or 3 weeks. That is quite different. I have already answered [US tourist visa - re-entry after three days possible for conference?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72059/us-tourist-visa-re-entry-after-three-days-possible-for-conference) with an opinion that that is achievable. Your situation is not quite *as* likely to be accepted, but nevertheless would *very* likely be. There is first hand experience from [@brhans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30555/brhans), where the chances were *less likely* (IMO), in a Comment:

> My wife did this twice before we were married and got her proper visa. We spent a few days in Costa Rica before returning to the USA. Both times she was readmitted without any trouble for another 90 days. Why Costa Rica? Because it was the closest country which is just far enough to trigger the VWP reset YMMV

Also:

> I recently came back to the US and was only issued 2 months this time, due to previously staying 6 months already.

from [re-entry to US from mexico after time frame of current B2 visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71557/re-entry-to-us-from-mexico-after-time-frame-of-current-b2-visa).

[@Michael Hampton](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3221/michael-hampton) has cautioned in a Comment:

> Going to secondary is almost guaranteed. Getting in is not.

Since the decision rests with CBP no guarantee of entry is possible. I have no idea of the probability of 'secondary' but even being questioned closely need not be something to fear, from what you have written. I suspect when reapplying you will have a ticket for your departure proposed for 2 or 3 weeks later and as long as you are convincing about not intending to reside in the USA the odds (as indicated in my linked A) seem very much in your favour.

See also [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/45718/4995) and bear in mind in particular the advice about documentation. If you are in USA to see sights I would imagine "I want to visit X,Y,Z (East Coast) because in the first 90 days I saw A,B,C,D,E,F,G (West Coast) and did not have time for everything" would go down better than "I enjoyed my 90 days now want 20 more".

Comment: Very helpful indeed