# How long do I need to be in my country for a B2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa

I have a question. I spent 6 months in New York City and I came back to my country. I can travel for 10 years. How long do I need to stay in my country before I can come back to NYC? Is 1 month enough?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but the answers to the following question answer your question as well: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67415/is-leaving-the-us-for-a-couple-of-days-enough-to-get-another-3-months-in-the-cou

Comment: It's essentially up to the discretion of the immigration officer.  If you come back a month later for a two-day visit, they're much more likely to let you in than if you come back a month later for another six-month visit.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specifically stated limit as far as how long you have to stay out of the US before returning - by the letter of the law you could stay out for 1 day (or even 1 hour) and then return.

However your re-admission to the USA is at the discretion of the immigration officers - even though you have a Visa they have no need to admit you to the country.  If they believe you are attempting to either "live" or "work" in the US, then you can expect to be refused entry, or at a minimum granted a shorter stay than the allowed 6 months.

The general rule of thumb is that you must spend as much time out of the country as you have spent in the country.  So if you've been in the country for 6 months, then you should spend 6 months out of the country.  That said, this is NOT a law, just a rule of thumb, so it will depend on the exact situation.  For example, if you can show proof that you will only be in the US for 2 weeks on your second stay then there is a higher chance of being readmitted than if you were planning to stay another 6 months.

Regardless of how long you are out of the country, be ready to answer a number of questions about what you did in the US on your previous stay, what you intend to do on your next stay, and how you are funding your time in the US.