# Re-entry to USA after flying back to the UK for 2 weeks (ESTA)

Tags: usa, esta, global-entry

I'm flying to the US in June for a total of 67 days in order to visit my girlfriend. I would have liked to stay the full 90 days but I've had to book an earlier return flight so I can come back to the UK to take an exam resit at my university. After the two week exam period, however, I have approximately another month before I have to start back at university.

Would flying back home after such a long stay in the US only to return 2 weeks later put me in danger of being denied entry at border control? I thought maybe if I was able to explain the reason for my return home and provide evidence that I'm starting back at university again, I'd be ok, but I don't want to jeopardise future trips to see my girlfriend just for the chance to spend a few extra weeks with her.

To complicate matters further, I've recently applied for the Global Entry program and am hoping to be approved before I leave the US. Would being a Global Entry member guarantee that I'd be able to return after my exam resit or would I still be taking a risk?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am *really* curious about the answer for GE members! Excellent question.

Comment: Your first question is well covered by [Two trips to the USA 3 weeks apart under ESTA scheme](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31488/two-trips-to-the-usa-3-weeks-apart-under-esta-scheme). As for Global Entry, it expedites your entry, but it does not guarantee you entry.

Comment: Have you ever read about anyone with GE denied entry? I fully understand it doesn't guarantee anything legally but in practice...?

Comment: @chx I suppose the likelihood of a GE member being denied is greater for a British citizen than for a Canadian.