# Onboarding in the US on ESTA or B-1

Tags: visas, esta, b1-b2-visas, work

I've been hired for a startup in the US. It is planned that I visit locally for 2 weeks for an oboarding session and to get to know the colleagues. Additionally, they would also pay for this trip. However the legality of this is still making me scratch my head, even after an immigration attorney said that ESTA and B-1 would pose no issue.

I would assume one can file "onboarding" under the "training" guise, under which it would be okay, given I can explain that I will not be able to do any actual "work". However since the US company is my sole employer, they're also the one paying me. I've read in a few places that this is an issue if the source of income is from a US company. While my income will come from an international payroll provider acting as a proxy and thus under "German" rule with euro payment, I wouldn't assume this is considered as a loophole?

Should I raise a comment about this just to be sure, or am I in the clear?

Comment: Are you planning to relocate to the US or work remotely?

Comment: With whom is your contract of employment?  That is, with what legal entity?  Is the payroll provider paying you from their own account or from funds they hold on behalf of the US company?  The question of whether this constitutes US-source income may not be immediately obvious without researching relevant precedents, and even then it might be "unsettled law."  Certainly in the absence of that factor, it seems okay since it sounds like meetings and, as you note, training.

Comment: I'm not planning to relocate just now, only visit for onboarding.

Good question @phoog, I am unable to answer this so far as these details will only be available to me within the next weeks.

Comment: A B-1 visa would have two advantages: 1, the visa officer will express an opinion on the legality of the trip, and 2, if you are denied entry, you'll be able to appeal. However, on the first point, if the visa officer decides that the plan is not allowed under B-1, you'll have a visa denial on your record, albeit for a relatively benign reason.  On the second point, you may not want to go through the appeal process, which involves going to immigration court.  I would ask the immigration attorney to describe what would happen if the immigration officer at the border decides to refuse admission.

Comment: Also, it's clear that if you worked for (e.g.) a German subsidiary of Microsoft, that is not US-source income.  The payroll processor arrangement, however, sounds different, for example if they act simply as an agent for the US company.

Comment: Taking a specific look in the intermediary Payroll FAQ, the precise wording they use is that they have a _separate_ agreement with the company and myself. In other words, I get hired and paid by the payroll company, and my company pays the payroll company separately. This still begs the question on "where exactly" this company is located, but I think in that sense I am not doing business with "my" company.

This also opens up a good question in terms of legality when it comes to possible later visas like H1B or similar.. hm, I think I might have to send an email asking for clarifications.

Comment: "In other words, I get hired and paid by the payroll company, and my company pays the payroll company separately" if that's the case then you have no US-source income (and the "payroll company" is more than just a payroll company).  Such an arrangement should have no impact on a future H-1B or other visa -- why would you think it might?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say L-1. It might have an impact on the "Must spend 1 year with the company" clause that's a requirement for L-1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK citizen, US company, living in UK: Can I use an ESTA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9245/uk-citizen-us-company-living-in-uk-can-i-use-an-esta)

Comment: Anyway you can't qualify as an L-1 intercompany transferee unless your employer is "doing business" in Germany.  It sounds like they are not.

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly fine, especially if you have been told it is fine by a qualified immigration attorney. You are visiting the US for training and business meetings, which are permitted under the Visa Waiver Program, and will continue to be paid by your German employer, not by the US company which is your German employer's client.

I've worked for US companies with similar arrangements to hire people who live in various countries, including Germany, and it's never been a problem when they've come to visit us for a couple of weeks.